# Useradd w/o Home directory

Tags: useradd

I created a user without home directory using `useradd -M Alice` and set a password. Now when I login, I get this message

```
No directory /home/Alice! Logging in with home= "/"
-bash-4.1$
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of last line and solve this issue?

Comment: Well since there is no /home directory set for Alice, you may want to go into /etc/passwd and add a directory for that user..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it like that:

```
mkdir /home/Alice

chown -R Alice:Alice /home/Alice
```

Even better if you use adduser instead of useradd, the directory will create automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The `-M` flag for `useradd` means "do not create the user's home directory", so the program has done what you asked.

You can fix the problem by creating a home directory for Alice and copying in the template files:

```
home=$(getent passwd Alice | cut -d: -f6)
uid=$(getent passwd Alice | cut -d: -f3)
gid=$(getent passwd Alice | cut -d: -f4)
mkdir -m755 "$home"
cp -a /etc/skel/. "$home"
chown -R $uid:$gid "$home"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Logging in with home= "/"`  means what it says. 
Since there is no home directory for the user, the login has used the root directory "/"

The `-bash-4.1$` is the default bash prompt.  You see that when there is no `~/.bashrc` nor other default bash files.  These are normally created, stored and updated in the user's home directory.

Using "/" as the home directory will cause other problems, as the user Alice most likely does not have permissions to write to the root directory of the filesystem.  :-)

As  roaima and Luciano Andress Martini wrote, you can fix this issue by creating a home directory.