# Question about the command "sudo su - (username)"

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, console

So I have a task I'm supposed to do and I need to login using a username I have created, which I did `sudo useradd (username)`, and also added a password using `sudo passwd (username)`, which all worked out fine. But when I try to login I get an error saying, `No Directory, logging in with HOME=/`. I tried entering the wrong password to see if my previous code for adding user was wrong,  and it did say `su: Authentication failure`, so I do not have an idea on what to do next, any help explaining and giving an answer would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Useradd w/o Home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285953/useradd-w-o-home-directory)

Comment: You don't need `sudo` and `su` in the same command. For your `sudo su - (username)` just use `sudo -u (username) -s` (or `sudo -su (username)` if you prefer the two options joined together).

Comment: Please write better titles than «Question about blah blah blah». Even something like «“sudo su” reports “No Directory”» would be an improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the new user, you didn't create a user home folder which usually is located in `/home/<username>`, that's why there is no HOME variable. To create a user with a home folder you should do `sudo useradd -m <username>`, with the `-m` you are creating the `/home/<username>` folder. You should also consider add the user to the `users` group, to create a user that is in the `users` group, do `sudo useradd -m -g users <username>`